# Pausing a while loop

Tags: python, loops

I have a query for a small program that I am running. I was wondering if there was any way to pause a while loop in python for an amount of time? Say for example if I wanted it to print something out, then pause for say (1) second, then print it out again?

There is not really a point to this program I am more doing it for something to do while bored.
I have checked other questions and none seemed to really answer what I was asking.

Comment: [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Comment: What questions did you already check and how did they not answer your question?

Comment: I probably didn't check hard enough but when I did check I couldn't find anything that answered my questions

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
while ...
    print your line
    time.sleep(1) # sleep for one second
```

[time sleep method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a function called `sleep` that does exactly what you want:

```
while true:
  print "Hello!\n"
  time.sleep(1)
```